# Can you group multiple rows all into one row by column value with Python using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby, pandas-merge

How do I change this:

| Date | URL | Description | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-17 14:24:52 | /XYBkLO | public | A |
| 2022-06-17 14:24:52 | /XYBkLO | public | B |
| 2022-06-17 14:24:52 | /XYBkLO | public | C |
| 2022-06-17 14:25:05 | /ZWrTVu | public | A |
| 2022-06-17 14:25:05 | /ZWrTVu | public | B |
| 2022-06-17 14:25:05 | /ZWrTVu | public | C |

To this:

| Date | URL | Description | Category | Date | URL | Description | Category | Date | URL | Description | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-17 14:24:52 | /XYBkLO | public | A | 2022-06-17 14:24:52 | /XYBkLO | public | B | 2022-06-17 14:24:52 | /XYBkLO | public | C |
| 2022-06-17 14:25:05 | /ZWrTVu | public | A | 2022-06-17 14:25:05 | /ZWrTVu | public | B | 2022-06-17 14:25:05 | /ZWrTVu | public | C |

I would like to keep everything with the same URL on one row, but I don't know how I could implement this using pandas. Is there perhaps another way or another library I should use? Could really use some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
from itertools import cycle, count, islice
from collections import defaultdict


def fn(x):
    d = defaultdict(lambda: count(1))
    names = cycle(x.columns)
    vals = x.values.ravel()

    return pd.DataFrame(
        [vals],
        columns=[f"{n}.{next(d[n])}" for n in islice(names, len(vals))],
    )


x = df.groupby("URL").apply(fn).reset_index(drop=True)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
                Date.1    URL.1 Description.1 Category.1               Date.2    URL.2 Description.2 Category.2               Date.3    URL.3 Description.3 Category.3
0  2022-06-17 14:24:52  /XYBkLO        public          A  2022-06-17 14:24:52  /XYBkLO        public          B  2022-06-17 14:24:52  /XYBkLO        public          C
1  2022-06-17 14:25:05  /ZWrTVu        public          A  2022-06-17 14:25:05  /ZWrTVu        public          B  2022-06-17 14:25:05  /ZWrTVu        public          C
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much. Every time I see an implementation using itertools and collections, it makes me wonder why these aren't emphasized more in python courses. Also, need to dive in more into pandas. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can look into pandas transpose function. [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)

Not 100% sure it will fit your use case but it seems like a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
(pd.concat(
    [df.set_index('URL',drop=False) for _,df in df.groupby('Category')]
    ,axis=1)
.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
    Date             URL    Description Category    Date             URL    Description Category  Date               URL    Description Category
0   6/17/2022 14:24 /XYBkLO public       A          6/17/2022 14:24 /XYBkLO public       B        6/17/2022 14:24   /XYBkLO public      C
1   6/17/2022 14:25 /ZWrTVu public       A          6/17/2022 14:25 /ZWrTVu public       B        6/17/2022 14:25   /ZWrTVu public      C
```